# K-theory for a (geometric) stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-stacks

There is a notion of $K$-theory for a manifold $M$.

> Is there a notion of $K$-theory for a stack $\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \text{Man}$ that is representable by a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$; that is $B\mathcal{G}\cong \mathcal{D}$?

One reference I could find for $K$-theory for Algebraic stacks is 
[Bertrand Toen‘s thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908097). Unfortunately, only title and abstract are in English and everything else is in French.

So, are there any references in English that introduce and discuss $K$-theory for stacks. What prerequisites would be needed to understand such theory for stacks?

Answer (score 2):

This is written nicely [here.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.1906.pdf) The the paper is called Loop Groups and Twisted $K$-theory I, by Freed, Hopkins and Teleman. Have a look at Section 3 and the Appendix.

Comment: Thank you :) I do not have enough background for understanding the introduction... I will give one more try after reading somethings mentioned in introduction.. :) Thanks again for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! There's no need to understand the stuff about loop groups, twistings etc. I guess you do need to be somewhat familiar with the Fredholm model for ordinary K theory

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I know one or two things about K theory.. I will read about Fredholm model first :) Thanks :)